# fullCalendar cannot redeclare

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

So I just started using fullCalendar on a php script.
I copied this line from the demo:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '\utilsController.php';
```

But when I try to use it, I get:

**Fatal error**:  Cannot redeclare strtotime() in

And if I comment that out, I get another redeclaration issue.
Do I have to rename those in my controller ?
Or is there another workaround ?
Redeclare means that it already has been defined, does that depend on my PHP Version ?

I have:
PHP Version 5.4.19

Comment: If there is a class or function definition in that file, you should always use `require_once`.

Comment: I did so, without improvement

Answer (score 1):

It seems strtotime() function is including multiple times.either you are loading utilsController.php' multiple times. In that case use require_once.
Otherwise check another file has same function strtotime() and you are including it at your current script.Make sure strtotime() function included once.

Comment: I updated it to: require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '\utilsController.php'; but nothing has changed. strtotime is a basic php function. Isn't it impossible to redeclare it anyway ?

Comment: You cannot re declare same function twice.Its an error.require and require_once stop your script if there is an error.you can try using include_once.

Comment: you can try this 
    if (!function_exists('strtotime')) {
    function strtotime()
    {
    your code here
    }
    
}